# Sort on Custom field in Drupal 7 views 3

Tags: sorting, view, drupal-7, drupal-views, field

How can I add sort on a custom added percentage field in Drupal 7 View?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean by 'custom added percentage field' however it shouldn't affect how views treats the field.

1. In views click 'Add' next to 'Sort Criteria'
2. Filter the list by 'Content' using the provided dropdown.
3. You should see the field in the list. Select it.
4. Click 'Apply'
5. Set the sort options as needed.

If that's too basic and the problem is that the field isn't shown in the list I'd suggest changing/adding a new question with more information.

Comment: the percentage field is not a field from view but added a handler for the same to calculate the percentage on runtime.